# Team City steps to Azure DevOps YAML

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I'm trying to duplicate these three build steps I have in Team City to Azure DevOps. I'd like to know what to add/change in my YAML file to accomplish the build steps in Team City. I'm providing my Team City steps and my YAML file from Azure DevOps.

I've tried to add multiple tasks but that didn't seem to work.

Team City build steps:

```
Step 1: Validate
Runner type: Maven (Runs Maven builds)
Execute:  If all previous steps finished successfully
POM file path: pom.xml
Goals: clean validate
Maven used: not specified
Additional Maven command line parameters: none specified
User settings provided by default
Maven metadata disabled: false
Use own local artifact repository: false
Build only modules affected by changes (incremental building): false
JDK home path: not specified
Build working directory: not specified
JVM command line parameters: not specified
Docker Settings
Docker Image: unset
Java code coverage: disabled

Step 2:
Runner type: Maven (Runs Maven builds)
Execute:  If all previous steps finished successfully
POM file path: pom.xml
Goals: package
Maven used: not specified
Additional Maven command line parameters: -Dapp.environment=test
User settings provided by default
Maven metadata disabled: false
Use own local artifact repository: false
Build only modules affected by changes (incremental building): false
JDK home path: D:\Programs\Java\jdk1.8.0_151
Build working directory: not specified
JVM command line parameters: not specified
Docker Settings
Docker Image: unset
Java code coverage: disabled

Step 3: SSH Upload to TEST 1
Runner type: SSH Upload (Deploys files/directories via SSH)
Execute:  If all previous steps finished successfully
Target host: "host IP":/opt/apache/tomcat/webapps/
Target port: default
Username: *****
Transport: SFTP
Source: target/*.war
```

YAML file:

```
# Maven
# Build your Java project and run tests with Apache Maven.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/java

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    goals: 'clean validate'
```

Comment: so eh, what doesnt work? what have you tried? why do you want to build and release in the build and not use releases for releasing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Team City steps to Azure DevOps YAML

AFAIK, the [Maven task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/maven?view=azure-devops) use the default lifecycle, which comprises of the following phases:

> - **validate** - validate the project is correct and all necessary    information is available
> - **compile** - compile the source code of the project
> - **test** - test the compiled source code using a suitable unit testing    framework. These tests should not require the code be packaged or
>     deployed
> - **package** - take the compiled code and package it in its distributable    format, such as a JAR.
> - **verify** - run any checks on results of integration tests to ensure    quality criteria are met
> - **install** - install the package into the local repository, for use as a    dependency in other projects locally
> - **deploy** - done in the build environment, copies the final package to    the remote repository for sharing with other developers and projects.

**These lifecycle phases are executed sequentially to complete the default lifecycle**. Given the lifecycle phases above, this means that when the default lifecycle is used, Maven will first validate the project, then will try to compile the sources, run those against the tests, package the binaries (e.g. jar), run integration tests against that package, verify the integration tests, install the verified package to the local repository, then deploy the installed package to a remote repository.

So, we do not need to specify each phase one by one when we use the task Maven task.

For you case, we just need to specify package in the `Goal(s)` option, do not need specify the `clean validate`. The Maven task will execute the lifecycle validate->compile->test->package:

The result:

[image]

And also you can see the test result under the test tab:

[image]

If we specify only `clean validate` in the the `Goal(s)` option, that task only execute this clean validate and we could not see the test result in the test tab:

[image]

[image]

Besides, if you want to deploy the package, you can specify the deploy in the `Goal(s)` option or you can use the [Copy Files Over SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh?view=azure-devops) task/ [FTP Upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/ftp-upload?view=azure-devops) task to deploy this task.

If that task is not work for you, please check the document [Get started with Maven packages in Azure DevOps Services and TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-maven?view=azure-devops) for some details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent! I did not know that Maven executed the previous lifecycle phases when I specify 'package'. Thank you!